# How can I get all tasks from Microsoft Project Professional using Add-in?

Tags: javascript, office-js, office-addins, ms-project, project-web-addins

I did try using the Office.context.document.getSelectedDataAsync(), but I need to click in the row to get the data from the task.

I need to get all tasks without clicking using Javascript inside the Add-in Project.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the available methods described for the [Office.Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.document?view=common-js-preview#office-office-document-getselectedtaskasync-member(1)) class in MSDN. The `getTaskAsync` or `getTaskByIndexAsync` method allows getting the Task Name, WSS Task Id, and ResourceNames for given `taskId`:

```
// Get data for the specified task.
function getTaskAsync() {
    if (taskGuid != undefined) {
        _projDoc.getTaskAsync(
            taskGuid,
            function (asyncResult) {
                if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
                    logMethodError("getTaskAsync", asyncResult.error.name,
                               asyncResult.error.message);
                } else {
                    var taskInfo = asyncResult.value;
                    var taskOutput = "Task name: " + taskInfo.taskName +
                                     "\nGUID: " + taskGuid +
                                     "\nWSS Id: " + taskInfo.wssTaskId +
                                     "\nResourceNames: " + taskInfo.resourceNames;
                    text.value = taskOutput;
                }
            }
        );
    } else {
        text.value = 'Task GUID not valid:\n' + taskGuid;
    } 
}
```

See [Create your first task pane add-in for Microsoft Project by using a text editor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/project/create-your-first-task-pane-add-in-for-project-by-using-a-text-editor) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But this does not work for me because I need to select the task without clicking and in this example above, it needs to be selected the task to get the taskGuid. It can see in the getSelectedTaskAsync() function when the taskGuid is assigned to use in the other functions later.

Comment: The `Document` object supports the following ways for developers to access document contents.
 - Selection-based access
 - Binding-based access

Comment: Read more about that in the [Common JavaScript API object model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/office-javascript-api-object-model) article.